# Pine script Exit Trade basis of other instrument

Tags: pine-script

On the basis of **GC1!** (CFD) I take trade on **GOLDM1!** (MCX).

I have written pine script strategy to indicate when to enter the trade.

Now I want to back test the strategy. i.e. Whenever condition to buy/sell occurs on **GC1!**", I want to trade using price of **GOLDM1!** at that point of time. The exit will also be driven by points of **GOLDM1!**.

When **GC1!** buy is triggered, at that time **GOLDM1!** price is **46100**.

The trade will be exited once the price of **GOLDM1!** becomes either **46000** or **46200**.

Can somebody please guide how can this be achieved?

Comment: I was also unable to find INR (India currency) symbol to be specified as strategy function parameter. Any input on that is much appreciated. I felt that will be linked to the solution so asking it upfront..

Answer (score 1):

To do that you need to use the `security` function, in your case this give:

```
security("GC1!",timeframe.period,close)
```

Use it as input for your strategy conditions and backtest it on GOLDM1.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I was thinking to do it that way.. However, I wil like to avoid that as I wanted to see actual buy sell signals on